# How to check the output of uploaded egg archive on scrapyd server?

Tags: scrapy, scrapyd

I was upload egg archive on the remote scrapyd server via the curl command they give me the following output. 
{"node_name": "iZwz9hlgd55ocg1gzzv0v9Z", "status": "ok", "project": "hi_there", "version": "r01", "spiders": 0}

And I want to check the output or execution of my egg archive. So how can I check that?